# HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-Port 534FLB Adapter and vSphere 6.5

Tags: hpe, lom

we have an HP C3000 blade enclosure equipped with 2 ProLiant BL460c Gen8 each with 1x HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-Port 534FLB Adapter and 1x HP Flex-10 10Gb 2-port 530M Adapter.

On interconnect bay 1 we have a HP 6125G/XG Blade Switch.

Our problem is that the vSphere 6.5 installed on the blades see the NIC as 1000 Mbps instead of 10000 Mbps.

I am sure there is something we are missing.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch blade only supports 1Gbps links for server downlinks (see here; https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c03499219).

Only the uplinks support 10Gbps.